# LifecycleOwner onChanged loops forever

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to insert a record into my room database whenever a new entry is made in my recycler view fragment. To add a new entry I observe the Live Data returned by my GetTasks method in my repository class and add any new items added to my shows array into my repository. 
The problem is that the onChanged method seems to be called whenever the data changes so when I insert data it calls itself again. This means it adds the same data into the room database infinitely.
How to I tell the onChanged method to stop and not call itself?

I've tried many things but I think I must be missing some built-in way to prevent this that I cant find online.

onChanged method in Main Activity:

```
ok_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    popupWindow.dismiss();
                    shows.add(new ShowItem(shows.size() + 1, showName.getText().toString()));
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(new MyItemRecyclerViewAdapter(shows));
                    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    final ShowRepository showRepository = new ShowRepository(getApplicationContext());

                    showRepository.getTasks().observe(test, new Observer<List<Show>>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Show> sections) {
                            for (ShowItem i : shows) {
                                showRepository.insertTask(i.getName());

                            }
                        }
                    });

                }
            });
```

DaoAccess:

```
@Dao
public interface DaoAccess {

    @Insert
    Long insertTask(Show show);


    @Query("SELECT * FROM Show ORDER BY id desc")
    LiveData<List<Show>> fetchAllTasks();


    @Query("SELECT * FROM Show WHERE id =:taskId")
    LiveData<Show> getTask(int taskId);


    @Update
    void updateTask(Show Show);


    @Delete
    void deleteTask(Show Show);
```

Show Class:

```
@Entity
public class Show {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int id;

    private String name;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Insert task in repository:

```
 public void insertTask(String name) {
        Show show = new Show();
        show.setName(name);
        insertTask(show);
    }

    public static void insertTask(final Show show) {
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
                showDatabase.daoAccess().insertTask(show);
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this if anyone's interested used this for onChanged:

```
 @Override
                    public void onChanged(@Nullable List<Show> sections) {
                        if (!hascalled) {
                            for (ShowItem i : shows) {
                                int count = 0;
                                for (Show s : sections) {
                                    if (i.getName().equals(s.getName())) {
                                        count++;
                                    }
                                }
                                if (count == 0) {
                                    showRepository.insertTask(i.getName());

                                }

                            }
                            hascalled = true;
                        }

                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and cleanest way would be to simply pass the item you want in the list to your Repository and add it to the Database, the recycled view is then hooked up to live data from `fetchAllTasks();` and will display all task, to see how to do this refer to this video example https://youtu.be/xPPMygGxiEo?t=231
Bonus: it will add nice Animations to your RecyclerView :)